# Javascript optional 0: .75 vs 0.75

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that is the following:

```js
let vector = new Vector2(mouseX / .75, mouseY / .75)
```

and this works perfectly. However, in VScode, the syntax highlighting becomes weird:
[image: syntax highlighting assuming it is a regex]

Almost as if the editor is thinking it is becoming a RegExp pattern.

**So, the question is, is `.75` an intended feature equivalent to `0.75` or not?**

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The two are the same thing, it is just a syntax error on VScode's part.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comments! So this is just a syntax highlighting error. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @Coder100 I think it could be useful to other users if renamed to represent the fact that it's a syntax highlighting error. This seems like a bug that should be reported to VSCode repo or the repo of whichever plugin provides highlighting for you.

Comment: @Klaycon alright, I will rename the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals) they are equivalent. It is probably just a syntax highlighting error.